# Wordpress page not found in Chrome, Safari

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I just moved my wordpress site to a new domain name and I am getting a "page not found" error for a couple of pages, but only in Chrome and Safari. It was working before I moved it.  I can still see the page in Firefox, when I have copy and paste the same address into Chrome and I still get "page not found".  This happens on 2 pages only.  I've tried disabling any non-essential plugins and it didn't make any difference.

Here is one of the pages not working - https://nemanjabogunovic.com/timeless-classics-sheet-music/

And here are some of the headers:
    Request URL: https://nemanjabogunovic.com/timeless-classics-sheet-music/
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 404 Not Found (from disk cache)
    Remote Address: 216.92.222.64:443
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 18:12:27 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.33
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.36
    Pragma: no-cache
    Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
    Link: https://nemanjabogunovic.com/wp-json/;  rel="https://api.w.org/"
 
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Provisional headers are shown
    Referer: https://nemanjabogunovic.com/products-page/
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2)   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
    X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:  3295AC425453EC81378F3CB16BA308F6

Answer (score 0):

can you try changing the permalinks back and forth?
Do this under settings > permalinks, swap to another setting, save, swap back. (Sometimes permalinks get stuck, and need to be refreshed.)

If you are using any plugins to cache your site, or make it run faster, try disabling them and checking the pages.

Try going to the page in question backend, and following the permalink from there, is it displaying when you do this?

Comment: I tried changing the permalinks back and forth, and that didn't do anything, but then that gave me the idea to go to the post and play with the link from there.  I just clicked edit on the link address, clicked OK and updated the page and now it seems to be working!  Thanks will pick your answer since it got me headed in the right direction

Comment: Thank you, trying to build up enough rep to actually comment on questions hehe!

Comment: actually, now it only works on Chrome on the computer I am working on, but just heard back from someone else saying it still doesn't work for them

Comment: Its important that you do "hard refreshes" when working with websites. In Chrome this is done by holding shift and pressing refresh. I think you are right, it is still not working. But it might explain why you are seeing different things in different browsers. Make sure you are experiencing the same in all browsers by doing hard refreshes... Because if it is truly different in different browsers this is a very weird issue.

Comment: Have you changed the "home" and "siteurl" cells in your database after moving the site? https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: yes, changed everything to the new site address.  I think if that was the problem there would probably be more than one page affected.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, I just checked and noticed that page gives me a 404 error and I've never visited before. Not a client-side caching issue at least.

Seems odd because it is a real post in WordPress - when I do a search 2 pages for the "Timeless Classics" page show up - https://nemanjabogunovic.com/?s=timeless

The one that doesn't work has this URL - https://nemanjabogunovic.com/timeless-classics-sheet-music/

Just checking this isn't the correct one instead? https://nemanjabogunovic.com/products-page/sheet-music-timeless-classics/timeless-classics-downloadable-e-book/

Comment: The second one is not the correct page.  It's the individual product page for one of the products on that page, but the correct page has additional products listed besides just the book.

Comment: @xena I'm at a loss! Does changing the URL of the page in the backend to something else fix the issue?

Comment: just saw your comment after I posted my own answer, yes that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

So this didn't really solve the mystery as to why it was happening, but I resolved the problem.  I ended up changing the post link by adding -tab to the end and it's working now.  Wish I thought of that sooner, would have saved me some trouble, but still a bit curious what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when zooming in with chrome it can cause WordPress to issue a 404. Zoom back out to 100% and it resolves it.